How can I make sure web crawlers see the navigation menu generated with JavaScript?
I run a website that publishes recipes and I'm having concerns about search engine bots not understanding the structure of the website. This has come to light after realizing that google is indexing very few of the pages, unless I manually submit each URL, which is far from ideal.
The website is created with HTML vanilla JavaScript and CSS.
The raw HTML holds the most of the structure, tags, text, images etc.
CSS implements the styling of course.
JavaScript provides some functionality to the site but more importantly, does some work saving tasks such as creating the navigation menu, the footer and the content for the recipe index page which displays links / images to each individual recipe page.
So I have one file app.js that creates the footer, the website navigation menu and adds simple functionality to each webpage (allows a user to toggle between "ingredients" & "cooking method".
A separate file recipecards.js holds a program that creates the content of the recipe index page.
I ran an audit scan using ahrefs site audit which came up with one deeply disturbing result for almost all pages:

Page has no outgoing links
Issue details:
If a page has no outgoing links, it is a "dead end" for both website visitors and search engine crawlers.
How to fix:
Check your website navigation and link architecture to make sure your website has no "dead ends."

I'm assuming that this must be because the crawler hasn't / isn't seeing the navigation menu, or the **footer ** for that matter, as each obviously have links that take the user elsewhere. It also makes me wonder if the web crawlers are actually seeing the "cooking methods" which are hidden until a user physically clicks an element to show those methods.
The most important thing here is the navigation menu, which must be present, otherwise the page would be a dead-end for the user (as reported by 'ahrefs' above) with no way to get to any other part of the website.
So, back to my question, where should I put the navigation menu script? Currently it is placed before the closing </body> tag of each page. It looks for one DOM element <div id="nav-container" class="nav-container"> which is the very first element in the <body>.
I'm now reading in several sources for example:
Where should I put  tags in HTML markup?
and MDN
that perhaps this navigation script needs to be loaded in the head of the document with an attribute of defer and/or async. However, I'm thinking asynccould potentially cause an error on a slow connection if the <div id="nav-container" class="nav-container"> has not been parsed, and I can't see how putting the script in the head with an attribute of defer would help, as the script still wont run until whole document has been parsed, unless I'm missing something here?
It's a fairly simple site if anyone wants to take a peek:
cooking website
But essentially how do I get round this problem of crawlers not seeing the nav menu and other content generated by JS.
The site is hosted on github, so there is no opportunity for server-side scripts generating the menu or other parts of the pages.
I appreciate any thoughts on this issue.
Thanks in advance.

I have 2 observations. First, your app.js creates a navigation menu using static values. By that I mean there is no api call to retrieve a dynamic list of hrefs so why on earth aren't you just coding a navigation menu into the html instead of using JavaScript once the DOM has loaded? I would also use a <nav> element instead of the dreaded <div> dance. Second, this may be out of your control, but the majority of the photos look like mobile phone quality images. I would pay an amateur photographer to do the recipe shots. High quality images are priceless when it comes to food.

The website is ever evolving, including the contents of the nav menu and any changes required to that would have to be manually applied to every single page, currently standing at around 90. As for the photo's, yep, it's an amateur website and the content I have (copy & images) is all I have to work with and there's nothing I can do about that

Since writing this question, one solution has entered my mind that perhaps a couple of hard-coded perma' links on the pages such as 'home' & 'contact us' might get around the "page is a dead end " problem in the web crawlers eyes

Have you considered just using server-side rendering for the majority of your html? The nav can be stored in one file or generated from a database query then included in each page. There is no need to hardcode a nav into lots of separate pages. What are you using on the server, Node, PHP, .Net etc?

I have yes, but the website is hosted on GitHub because the website owner doesn't have the budget  for a payed hosting solution and there are no server side languages available on GitHub, meaning it only serves up static pages. I have looked at several 'free hosting' solutions and was considering 000webhost before they changed their T's & C's and now I'm leaning towards Infinity hosting, which at least would give me PHP to work with, however, 'free hosting' always has its limitations, but, that's what I have to work with. It would be nice to have professionally produced photo's too...

You should really consider a static site generator then. It sounds like you are doing way too much manual work. There tons to choose from.
